# How to set the starting point of the y-axis in a line chart to turn the line into a curve

Tags: lightningchart

in lightningchart, How to set the starting point of the y-axis in a line chart to turn the line into a curve[image]

My current effect is too abrupt, the value may suddenly become very large or small after running for a period of time in a certain area, how to adjust